# PHP conditional return statement?

Tags: php, conditional-statements

Can someone tell me what the condition is in this php statement?

```
return $node->type == 'article' ? mymodule_page_article($node) : mymodule_page_story($node);
```

I'm sorry if this is not the place to ask such a simple question but I'm finding it difficult to look up specific code structure (especially when I don't know the name of it).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a [ternary operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary).

It's equivalent to

```
if( $node->type == 'article' ) {
    return mymodule_page_article($node);
} else {
    return mymodule_page_story($node);
}
```

What it does is: if the stuff before the `?` is true, return the result of the expression in the first clause (the stuff between `?` and `:`). If it's false, then it returns the result of the second clause (the stuff after the `:`).

Answer (score 2):

This is the ternary operator `?:` and can be expanded as follows:

```
if ($node->type == 'article') {
  return mymodule_page_article($node);
} else {
  return mymodule_page_story($node);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is equivalent to:

```
if($node->type == 'article')
{
     return mymodule_page_article($node);
}
else
{
     return mymodule_page_story($node);
}
```

This is called the ternary operator. See the section on it here for more information: http://www.php.net/operators.comparison

Answer (score 0):

this is a ternary expression.

the condition is $node->type == 'article' and if it's true it does mymodule_page_article($node) else mymodule_page_story($node)

Answer (score 0):

If type of node is equal to 'article' do `mymodule_page_article($node)`, if it isn't equal then do `mymodule_page_story($node)`

Answer (score 0):

Use Ternary operator

return isset($node->type == 'article') ? mymodule_page_article($node) : mymodule_page_story($node)